# Unable to get Events from specific Calendar

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get events from a Specific Calendar through MSGraph-SDK (dotnet) - 
Getting the events for my 'default' calendar is not a problem:

```
var calendar = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView.Request(options).GetAsync();
if (calendar?.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Event current in calendar)
       etc. //All good here
```

But when trying to get events from a specific calendar gives me an error (no details about the error provided)

```
var calOne = await graphClient.Me.Calendars[cal1].CalendarView.Request().GetAsync(); // <=Error
```

(Please note that `cal1` is a string with a correct calendar Id)
Chances are I'm missing something, just don't know what.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I figure this out. Here's how to get events from a specific calendar     `var hqEvents = await graphClient.Me.Calendars[hqCalId].Events.Request(options).GetAsync();`  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. Here's how to get events from a specific calendar:

```
var hqEvents = await graphClient.Me.Calendars[hqCalId].Events.Request(options).GetAsync();
```